# Valgrind returns "Illegal instruction" reguardless of options. Raspbian

Tags: linux, apt, raspbian, valgrind

I'm trying to get Valgrind running on my raspberry pi zero W. I've installed it through apt but running it returns "Illegal instruction" no matter what.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documnents/test $ valgrind --help
Illegal instruction
```

How can I debug or fix this? Thanks!

Information:

```
Valgrind Version: (1:3.13.0-2~bpo9+1)

pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.42+ #1219 Tue May 14 21:16:38 BST 2019 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: do a `which valgrind` to find the path of your valgrind executable, then do a `file X` where X is that path.

Comment: @LawrenceC ```/usr/bin/valgrind: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable```

Comment: Then almost certainly the error message comes from a command called by that script. Can you run the script with `sh -x /usr/bin/valgrind --help` and [edit] your question to include the resulting output?

Comment: @tripleee it's failing on ```exec /usr/bin/valgrind.bin --help```

Comment: I "gave up" and just built and installed valgrind from their repo.  That works.  Thank-you for your help!

Comment: As such, finding the actual binary was a good first step towards finding out what was wrong, but that's all moot now I suppose.